# How to change background color of active nav-link?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, css-selectors

I have a darkmode version of my asp.net site and everything works except the active card-header tab. Ive tried a bunch of different CSS to figure it out but i cant get it.

I thought something like this would work

```
.nav-link > .active {
    background-color: var(--bg);
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

But it does not. Here is the code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div class="card login-logout-tab">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Identity/Account/Login">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Sign up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

<script>
    $(function () {
        var current = location.pathname;
        $('.nav-tabs li a').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (current.indexOf($this.attr('href')) !== -1) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

These are the areas that i want to change the background color for:

```
<li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link active" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Sign up</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.nav-link > .active` would select a (direct) *child* element of the element which has the `.nav-link` class. But in your case the `.active` class is applied to the `.nav-link` element itself (as an additional class) – see your example `<a class="nav-link active" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Sign up</a>`

So the selector for that has to be `.nav-link.active { ... }` (without a space in -between), which selects any element that has *both* of these classes.

Comment: This still doesnt work. .nav-link.active still has a white background on my active tab while in darkmode

Answer (score 0):

According to your css `.nav-link > .active` the nav-link doesnot have a direct child element so it will not work.

So, First solution change class in your css .nav-link to .nav-item

```
.nav-item > .active {
    background-color: var(--bg);
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

Or, you can also do.

```
.nav-link.active {
    background-color: var(--bg);
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

Comment: Neither of those options work. the active tab is still white on darkmode